# Open Database Synchronously in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, synchronous, opendatabase

Trying to open a database synchronously using JavaScript. My code looks something like this. Whenever I run it on Chrome, I get the following 2 errors

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'file:///C:/Users/KH1483/Desktop/web%20sql/worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'. dbSync.html:23
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined dbSync.html:16

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script> 
function test() { 
db = openDatabase("Foo", "", "", 1); 
if (db) 
    alert("Opened Foo"); 
else 
    alert(2); 
db = openDatabase("WorkerFoo", "", "", 1); 
var query='select * from test';
db.transaction(function(tx){ 
    result=tx.executeSql(query); 
if(result.rows.length>0){ 
for(var l=0; l<result.rows.length; l++){
    alert('Result: '+result.rows.item(l)['id']);
}
} 
}); 

worker = new Worker('worker.js'); 
worker.onmessage = function(event) { 
alert(event.data); 
} 

} 

</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="test()"> 
</body> 
</html>
```

/* Worker.js starts here */

```
db = openDatabaseSync("WorkerFoo", "", "", 1); 
if(db) postMessage('Web Worker DB Synchronous Built');


try { 
var query='create table if not exists test (id int(10))';
db.transaction( function(tx){ tx.executeSql(query, [], null,null); });
postMessage('Table Created');
}catch(err){ 
postMessage("Exception: " + err + "; code = " + err.code); 
} 

var query='insert into test (id) values (100)';
db.transaction( function(tx){ tx.executeSql(query, [], null,null); });
postMessage('Data Inserted');

var query='select * from test';


db.transaction(function(tx){ 
result=tx.executeSql(query);
if(result.rows.length>0){ 

postMessage("Data Length="+result.rows.length); 
for(var l=0; l<result.rows.length; l++){
postMessage('Result: '+result.rows.item(l)['id']);
}

} 
});
```

Comment: In line `result=tx.executeSql(query); `, it returns `undefined`

Comment: How were you able to get to this line ?
I am unable to call the worker even.